# Netlify CMS not able to update/replace image that has been optimized in Gatsby.js

Tags: reactjs, graphql, netlify-cms

From my markdown file `index.md`,...

```
---
templateKey: home-page/index
image1: /img/City-Picture.jpg
---
```

...I want to make an optimized `image1` available to the `graphql` here in `templates/index.js`...

```
export const homePageQuery = graphql`
  query HomePage($id: String!) {
    markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id }) {
      frontmatter {
        welcome_description
        image1 {
          childImageSharp {
            sizes(maxWidth: 590) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

But I get this error in the terminal...

```
GraphQL Error Field "image1" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields.
2 |   query HomePage($id: String!) {
3 |     markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id }) {
4 |       frontmatter {
5 |         welcome_description
6 |         image1 {
  |                ^
7 |           childImageSharp {
8 |             sizes(maxWidth: 590) {
9 |               ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes
10|             }
11|           }
12|         }
13|       }
14|     }
```

(I won't get his error if I refrain from optimizing `image1`.)

In `gatsby-config.js`, I have these plugins placed before `gatsby-source-filesystem` ...

```
`gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
`gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
```

I'm not sure why GraphQL considers `image1` to be type "String".  In `index.md`, even if I change `image1: /img/City-Picture.jpg` to the relative path of the image (`image1: ../..static/img/City-Picture.jpg`), I still get the same error.

Of course, I'd prefer to leave it at `/img/City-Picture.jpg` because only that will work in Netlify CMS for image updating.  In `config.yml` for Netlify CMS, I have...

```
media_folder: static/img
public_folder: /img
```

...which I think I'd need to keep the same in order for the image editor to work in the CMS.

I have attempted to implement to recently built plugin [`gatsby-remark-relative-images`](https://github.com/danielmahon/gatsby-remark-relative-images)  which is meant to compensate for Netlify CMS's inability to use relative paths, but I could not get it to work.

There is a active discussion about this at https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms/issues/325, but so far I could not get any of the solutions to work.

As of now, I have a dilemma of two imperfect choices:
1. Having the ability to edit images in Netlify CMS, but not having the ability to optimize those images via `gatsby-image`.
2. Not having the ability to edit images in Netlify CMS, but then having the ability to optimize those images via `gatsby-image`.

I'd much prefer to have the best of both worlds if possible.  Any insights on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question description is mixed. 1. You are mentioning the graphql problem. 2. You are referring to issue on GitHub which is about uploading images. 3. You are saying about optimizing images.

Answer (score 2):

I actually just replaced my Netlify CMS with Contentful CMS (free tier).  It is much easier at Contentful CMS to work with images.  To do so, I viewed an [excellent tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek4o40w1tH4&index=1&list=PL8KiuH6vpACV-F7jXribe4YveGBhBeG9A) on setting up Gatsby with Contentful CMS.

Answer (score 0):

According to the question:

> Netlify CMS not able to update/replace image that has been optimized in Gatsby.js

Here's how the flow work:

1. Changes made in NetlifyCMS
2. Changes trigger the build
3. Gatsby kicks in

... *(and do as mentioned in the `config.yml` file)*

NetlifyCMS doesn't work this way, it only fetches the data from the `.git` repository and show them in the UI.

Whereas Gatsby starts working when the changes are committed, and all the work was done by the Gatsby *(converting markdown files, optimizing images)* is on the server.

Since Gatsby doesn't commit any changes to the repository, hence NetlifyCMS doesn't know anything about optimizing the images or converting markdown files into `.html` files.